# Export tables from Snowflake to SQL Server (AWS)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake, I need to export some tables from our Snowflake DW to SQL Server which is hosted on AWS Cloud. and can we automate it like a daily Job somewhere to fetch realtime data from Snowflake? can somebody guide me with the steps needed for this?

Comment: There are a range of options. Do you have a preferred ETL / data integration platform that you use? All the major ones have Snowflake connectors. You can also copy out tables to an external stage, which would include Azure Blob storage. Here's how to do that: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html

Comment: we don't have any on premises server. we need to use Cloud Services for daily data feed either they're on Snowflake end or AWS end. thanks for your help...

Comment: If you have a cloud ETL / data integration platform you could use it. If not, the most common approach would be to export to CSV or another format in Azure Blob. The link above discusses how to do exports as CSV to an "external stage". An external stage includes Azure Blob storage. Edit: Also, you can use the Snowflake function GET_DDL https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/get_ddl.html to get the DDL definitions. You'll have to modify them somewhat to create the objects in SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks @GregPavlik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way - without buying a third party tool - might be a SQL Server linked server to Snowflake.  The steps are documented: https://snowflakecommunity.force.com/s/article/how-to-set-up-a-linked-server-from-sql-server-to-snowflake

Once you've setup the linked server a recurring SQL Server agent job can run the pull.